# NoClassDefFoundError: Problems with linking my own jar to Android project

Tags: java, android, jar

So, I'm trying to develop a client-server application for Android. For this purposes I've created an engine, that I'm going to use both in server and in Android applecation and export it as a .jar file.

There was no issues in using this engine.jar on server side (simple background java application), but I faced some problems with linking mention .jar file to my android project.

To link engin.jar I follow some steps:

- created "libs" dir in my android project
- imported engine.jar in this folder

After this engine.jar could be seen in Android Dependences group. Also I can use all classes from that .jar, Eclipse doesn't mark them as error.
My project compiles fine, but the app crashes when I'm trying to create any object from engine.jar with the following error:

> 04-15 23:18:12.885: E/AndroidRuntime(17409):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Common.Message.Message

I guess I've tried everything. Could anyone share his ideas about the root cause of described situation?

Comment: Did you add the jar file to the build path in Eclipse? It should appear in the "Referenced Libraries" group.

Comment: @smichak in SDK Tools v18+, libraries in the "libs" folder are automatically added to the build path via "Android Dependencies"

Comment: As was said in previous comment "Referenced Libraries" had been renamed into "Android Dependencies" since 17 revision of Android SDK

Comment: Is `Common.Message.Message` supposed to be one of your classes? If so, aren't you missing a package name?

Comment: I guess no. I've imported my class as follows `import Common.Message.Message;` and created an instance of imported class  `Message m = new Message("id");`

Comment: Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Please post the whole logcat when you have this error.

Comment: When you copy engine.jar into the folder, did you select Copy or Link?  I've had similar issues when trying to Link jars in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too experienced the same problem. I resolved it by doing the following:

Right click on the project directory -> `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path` -> Select Tab `Order and Export` -> Check/Select the checkboxes of the concerned `.jar` files -> Press `Ok`.

Hope this resolves your problem as well.

Comment: BOOM that appeared to be it. Many thanks, this was a real emergency.

Comment: So why don't you grant @Arun his bounty?

Comment: Artem, I tried, but the system wouldn't allow me, as not enough time had passed.

Answer (score 0):

For future use:

Create a folder named "libs" in the root of the project and then add the jar you wish to add and all the export stuff mentioned in the previous comment will be automatically done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your server and client dont have the same common jar of class's. When coding client server app's you need to ensure that there is some common code project, mostly this will become a lib file in future.